# Problem using head to remove last line of file

Tags: bash

I was recently looking for a way to remove the last line of a file `foo.txt` and came across the following solution

> head -n -1 foo.txt temp.txt; mv temp.txt foo.txt

which works fine. However, I also tried simply

> head -n -1 foo.txt > foo.txt

which to my surprise left `foo.txt` an empty text file, and I would like to know why.

I'm just getting started with unix, so it's possible my question is rather silly.

Comment: cat foo.txt | head -n-1 > foo.txt

Comment: @PiyushJain That appears to have the same issue.

Comment: cat lol.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
  
cat lol.txt | head -n-1 > lol.txt  

cat lol.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the redirect `>` happens *before* the rest of the command.

If you want to do an inplace edit, you'll need a suitably aware utility. e.g. `perl` or `sed`. (Or just do the `mv` like the original snippet suggested)

Comment: Or use `ksh93` and its `<>;` redirection operator, or use GNU `truncate` after having determined the size of the last line.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite understand why this results in foo.txt being empty.

Comment: Because `>` opens and truncates the file, ready to have data put into it. And then the rest of the command happens to fill it with data... so it's already empty _before_ you start reading it.